# How can I recover an RDS instance if I lose access to the encryption key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds

According to [the documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html.), RDS instances, backups and snapshots are encrypted using the same CMK. But what happens when I lose access to that key? Is there a way to recover? Shouldn't backups be encrypted with a different key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about accidentally deleting a CMK, AWS enforces a [waiting period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/deleting-keys.html#deleting-keys-how-it-works) of at least 7 days. During that time, you can undelete the key.

If you're still uncomfortable with having everything encrypted with the same key, you can [copy a snapshot and use a different CMK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html#USER_CopySnapshot.Encryption). In fact, you *have* to use a different CMK if you're making a cross-region copy.

Comment: But if I take a snapshot and then encrypt it with another CMK, wouldn't I still need the original key to decrypt what's left after the other CMK finishes decrypting the snapshot? That is, isn't the process Encrypt DB with Key_A --> Take snapshot --> Encrypt snapshot with Key_B --> Decrypt snapshot with Key_B --> [here you'd have to decrypt with Key_A]?

Comment: No, when you copy a snapshot it decrypts with the original key and then encrypts with the new key. At least that's how I remember it, although it's literally been years since I copied a snapshot using a different account (and therefore a different key). But it's the only way that it _could_ work with a cross-region copy, so I feel confident in saying so.